# Avoiding "This Website Wants to Run the Following Add-on" in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, add-on

I am playing an alert in IE8 if I open the home page of my application. I am using jQuery to embed the sound file in the page.

```
if (isAlert) {
    if(!isAdded){
        if ($("#beapImg").length!= 0) {

        } else {
            $('body').append('<embed src="'+alerts+'" id="beapImg" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="true">');
            isalertAdded=true;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting:

**`This website wants to run the following add-on: ‘Windows Media Player Core’ from ‘Microsoft Corporation’`**

at the top of the page. If I click Add Add Ons, then I am able to hear the sound.

Can anyone please suggest how to avoid this programmatically and advise me as to why I am getting the above alert?

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue only when running your script from a local file or also when you run your page on a server?

Comment: Are you just doing this on a local machine or is it hosted or on a server?

Comment: Am getting the above if its hosted on server !

Answer (score 2):

How to Avoid the Warning?

If you are a web developer, you should use the safer versions of these controls. Please do not encourage your users to approve controls when safer options are pre-approved. If you are getting these warnings, you are probably using some very old sample code:

- Windows Media Player: Do not use MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.1, or other
  older techniques. Use wmplayer.ocx.
- QuickTime: Do not use QuickTimeCheckObject.QuickTimeCheck.1. Instead,
  use QuickTime.QuickTime.
- MSXML: Do not use MSXML 5.0.  See this sample code to detect the
  right version of MSXML in IE7.

Taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2007/04/25/this-website-wants-to-run-the-following-add-on.aspx).

Comment: Yeah i already referred the above link , but i dont understand using "wmplayer.ocx" part .

Comment: Read this tutorial to know all about it... http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/12/11/the-scripting-guys-really-do-rock-part-1-of-4.aspx